# " Climb " vs " Climb out "

Tags: differences

What are the differences between the two acts **"Climb" vs "Climb out"** ?

thanks in advance

Comment: This should be rather easily discovered by a Google search of each of those terms.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My thoughts are that this is not about the word climb but about the word following climb. I climb out of the bathtub (because I am in in). I climb down from a tree (because I am up in it.) I climb up the stairs because that shows directionality. Well I guess we don't climb down the stairs so that is actually redundant. My first time answering so shall be interested in what others have to say! Margie

Comment: Unfortunately others say "this question is off topic, as this site requires basic research". We don't encourage answering questions like this, we just try to close them as quickly as possible. I'd suggest taking [The Tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how the site works, and reading [what's on topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what's off topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).